# How do you parallelize the flipping of image with Pthreads?

Tags: c++, cmake, pthreads

I'm new to `Pthreads` and `c++` and trying to parallelize an image flipping program. Obviously it isnt working. I'm told I need to port some code from an Image class but not really sure what porting means. I just copied and pasted the code but I guess that's wrong.

I get the general idea. allocate the workload, intitialize the threads, create the threads, join the threads and define a callback function.

I'm not totally sure what the `cells_per_thread` should be. I'm pretty sure it should be the image `width * height / threads`. Does that seem correct?

I'm getting multiple errors when compiling with cmake.

its saying `m_thread_number`, `getWidth`, `getHeight`, `getPixel`, `temp` are not define in the scope. I assume thats because the Image class code isn't ported?

**PthreadImage.cxx**

```
 //Declare a callabck fucntion for Horizontal flip
    void* H_flip_callback_function(void* aThreadData);

    PthreadImage PthreadImage::flipHorizontally() const
    {

        if (m_thread_number == 0 || m_thread_number == 1)
        {
            return PthreadImage(Image::flipHorizontally(), m_thread_number);
        }
        else
        {

            PthreadImage temp(getWidth(), getHeight(), m_thread_number);

            //Workload allocation
            //Create a vector of type ThreadData whcih is constructed at the top of the class under Struct ThreadData. Pass in the number of threads.
            vector<ThreadData> p_thread_data(m_thread_number);

            //create an integer to hold the last element. inizialize it as -1.
            int last_element = -1;
            //create an unsigned int to hold how many cells we need per thread. For the image we want the width and height divided by the number of threads. 
            unsigned int cells_per_thread = getHeight() * getWidth() / m_thread_number;
            //Next create a variable to hold the remainder of the sum. 
            unsigned int remainder = getHeight() * getWidth() % m_thread_number;

            //print the number of cells per thread to the console
            cout << "Default number for cells per thread: " << cells_per_thread << endl;

            //inizialize the threads with a for loop to interate through each thread and populate it
            for (int i = 0; i < m_thread_number; i++)
            {
                //thread ids correspond with the for loop index values. 
                p_thread_data[i].thread_id = i;
                //start is last element + 1 i.e -1 + 1 start = 0.
                p_thread_data[i].start_id = ++last_element;
                p_thread_data[i].end_id = last_element + cells_per_thread - 1;
                p_thread_data[i].input = this;
                p_thread_data[i].output = &temp;

                //if the remainder is > thats 0 add 1 to the end them remove 1 remainder. 
                if (remainder > 0)
                {
                    p_thread_data[i].end_id++;
                    --remainder;
                }

                //make the last element not = -1 but = the end of the threads.
                last_element = p_thread_data[i].end_id;

                //print to console what number then thread start and end on 
                cout << "Thread[" << i << "] starts with " << p_thread_data[i].start_id << " and stops on " << p_thread_data[i].end_id << endl;

            }

            //create the threads with antoher for loop
            for (int i = 0; i < m_thread_number; i++)
            {
                pthread_create(&p_thread_data[i].thread_id, NULL, H_flip_callback_function, &p_thread_data[i]);
            }

            //Wait for each thread to complete;
            for (int i = 0; i < m_thread_number; i++)
            {
                pthread_join(p_thread_data[i].thread_id, NULL);
            }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

**Callback function**

```
//Define the callabck fucntion for Horizontal flip
void* H_flip_callback_function(void* aThreadData)
{


    //convert void to Thread data
    ThreadData* p_thread_data = static_cast<ThreadData*>(aThreadData);

    int tempHeight = temp(getHeight());
    int tempWidth = temp(getWidth());

    for (int i = p_thread_data->start_id; i <= p_thread_data->end_id; i++)
    {

        // Process every row of the image
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m_height; ++j)
        {
            // Process every column of the image
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_width / 2; ++i)
            {
                (*(p_thread_data->output))(              i, j) = getPixel(m_width - i - 1, j);
                (*(p_thread_data->output))(m_width - i - 1, j) = getPixel(              i, j);
            }


         }
    }
```

}

**Image class**

```
#include <sstream> // Header file for stringstream
#include <fstream> // Header file for filestream
#include <algorithm> // Header file for min/max/fill
#include <numeric> // Header file for accumulate
#include <cmath> // Header file for abs and pow
#include <vector>

#include "Image.h"


//-----------------
Image::Image():
//-----------------
    m_width(0),
    m_height(0)
//-----------------
{}


//----------------------------------
Image::Image(const Image& anImage):
//----------------------------------
    m_width(anImage.m_width),
    m_height(anImage.m_height),
    m_p_image(anImage.m_p_image)
```

//----------------------------------

**Image class code to be ported**

```
//-----------------------------------
Image Image::flipHorizontally() const
//-----------------------------------
{


// Create an image of the right size
    Image temp(getWidth(), getHeight());

    // Process every row of the image
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m_height; ++j)
    {
        // Process every column of the image
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tempWidth / 2; ++i)
        {
                temp(i, j) = getPixel(tempWidth - i - 1, j);
                temp(tempWidth - i - 1, j) = getPixel(i, j);
        }
    }


      return 0;
```

}

I feel like its pretty close. Any help greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Ok, so this is the correct code for anyone wasting their time on this.

There was obviously a fair few things wrong.

1. I don't know why there was 3 for loops. There should be 2. 1 for Rows and 1 for columns.
2. The `cells_per_thread` should be `pixels_per_thread` and **rows/threads** as @Larry B suggested not **ALL** the pixels per thread.
3. You can use -> to get members of a pointer i.e `setPixel(),`getPixel` etc. Who knew that!?
4. There was a data structure that was pretty inportant for you guys but I forgot.

   struct ThreadData 
   {
       pthread_t thread_id;
       unsigned int start_id;
       unsigned int end_id;
       const Image* input;
       Image* output;
   };

**Correct Callback**

```
void* H_flip_callback_function(void* aThreadData)
{

     //convert void to Thread data
     ThreadData* p_thread_data = static_cast<ThreadData*>(aThreadData);

     int width = p_thread_data->input->getWidth();

     // Process every row of the image
     for (unsigned int j = p_thread_data->start_id; j <=p_thread_data->end_id; ++j)
     }
         // Process every column of the image
         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width / 2; ++i)
         {
             p_thread_data->output->setPixel(i,j,  p_thread_data->input->getPixel(width - i - 1, j));
             p_thread_data->output->setPixel(width - i - 1, j, p_thread_data->input->getPixel(i, j));
         }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

So now this code compiles and flips.
Thanks!

Comment: "I assume thats because the Image class code isn't ported?" - We could only **guess** what this Image class contains. But your current code definitely lacks of definitions of the variables.

Comment: To "port" means to copy/paste with understanding of what has to be adjusted afterwards. ;-)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry! I've added some more of the image class. Is this enough to get whats going on?

Comment: If you already have a serial version, using `concurrency::parallel_for` can save you a lot of time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/parallel-algorithms?view=vs-2019 if you are not developing on Windows, you can have a look at Boost

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez no I'm really developing on a super computer but I prefer to write the code in VS and send over using WinSCP. I must use Pthreads and openMP then get the time its takes to process serial, pthreads and open MP

Comment: Since the code doesn't define aforementioned variables and functions, it is not enough. But even posting the whole code would be not enough: It seems you don't understand that code, and we unlikely can help you in that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well ok can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Why is temp not defined in the scope? I've created a PthreadImage called temp?!

Comment: "Why is temp not defined in the scope?" - In **which** scope? You have over 10 usages of `temp` variable, we could only guess which exact usage is warned by the compiler. Or we could try to read the code with broken indentation. The right direction would be to read original code and trying to understand it. Only after basic understanding you may start "porting" the code, step by step. In that case, would you face with a problem during the coding, you will be able to formulate the problem in a way clear for others.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Ok I've edited the code above, can you check? the only errors i'm getting now are the `m_height`, `m_width` and `getPixel` variables in the callback function. I know i'm supposed to just switch the pixels. Using serial code as in the `Image` class thats easy but how do I do that with Pthreads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general strategy for porting single threaded code to a multi-thread version is essentially rewriting the existing code to **divide the work into self contained units of work** that you can hand off to a thread for execution.

With that in mind, I don't agree with your implementation of `H_flip_callback_function`:

```
void* H_flip_callback_function(void* aThreadData)
{
    //convert void to Thread data
    ThreadData* p_thread_data = static_cast<ThreadData*>(aThreadData);

    // Create an image of the right size
    PthreadImage temp(getWidth(), getHeight(), m_thread_number);

    int tempHeight = temp(getHeight());
    int tempWidth = temp(getWidth());

    for (int i = p_thread_data->start_id; i <= p_thread_data->end_id; i++)
    {
        // Process every row of the image
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < tempHeight; ++j)
        {
            // Process every column of the image
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tempWidth / 2; ++i)
            {
                temp(i, j) = getPixel(tempWidth - i - 1, j);
                temp(tempWidth - i - 1, j) = getPixel(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At face value, it looks like all your threads will be operating on the whole image. If this is the case, there is no real difference between your single and multi-thread version as you're just doing the same work multiple times in the multi-thread version.

I would argue that the smallest self contained unit of work would be to horizontally flip a single row of the image. However, if you have less threads than the number of rows, then you could allocate **(Num rows / Num threads) to each thread**. Each thread would then flip the rows assigned to it and the main thread would collect the results and assemble the final image.

With regards to your build warnings and errors, you'll have to provide the complete source code, build settings, environment, etc..

Comment: Thanks for your help! Thats what I thought, however i'm not sure how to exactly implement getting a single row of the image. https://github.com/DavieB22/PthreadsImageProcessing/tree/master/PthreadsImageProcessing this is a link to the project if you'd be so kind as to see what i'm missing?

Comment: @DaviebPrime, I think you have code already that iterates over a row of your image in the inner for loop: `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tempWidth / 2; ++i)`. Instead of having every thread iterate over the entire range of [0: height), assign certain ranges of j to each thread. As an example, if you have two threads, then you could give thread 1 the range of j to be [0, height/2) and thread 2 can work on the range [height/2, height).